# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<FormField> to Iterator

Tags: android

im trying to create a MUC room creator to my app, as i almost see every one has done and is in the aSmack's tutorial, i see every one did this:

```
  for (Iterator fields =  form.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
              FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
    if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable()!= null) {
                  // Sets the default value as the answer
                  submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
              }
```

but when i use that gives this error:

```
  Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<FormField> to Iterator
```

has any thing changed since then or what is wrong guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, your code has two bad things:

1) The way you specified your `Iterator` is raw. This would work, but it's a good practice to define the type of the `Iterator` in order to avoid undesirable behaviors. If you expect `FormField`s, your should define your iterator like `Iterator<FormField>`.

2) I don't know your concrete example, but if it's giving that error, undoubtfully the `getFields()` method is returning a `List<FormField>`s.

You probably wanted to call:

```
for (Iterator<FormField> fields =  form.getFields().iterator(); fields.hasNext();) {
  ...
}
```